# tsql how to get unique rows with first and end date times

Tags: t-sql

When I run the sub queries separately, I get unique dates for each row but together I am getting repeating rows. How do I correct?

```
SELECT a.*
    ,b.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT serial_number_id
        ,s_start_dttm
        ,x_dept_id AS dept_a
        ,x_dept_name AS dept_name_a
        ,event_type_c AS event_type_a
        ,evnt.NAME AS event_name_a
    FROM TABLE x
    WHERE event_type_c = 3
    ) a
    ,(
        SELECT DISTINCT serial_number_id
            ,s_end_dttm
            ,x_dept_id AS E_x_DEPT_ID
            ,x_DEPT_NAME AS E_x_DEPT_NAME
            ,event_type_c AS event_type_b
            ,event_name AS event_type_b
        WHERE event_type_c = 4
        ) b
WHERE a.serial_number_id = b.serial_number_id
```

Comment: Please could you add some test data and expected output.

Comment: Try adding AND a.dept_a = b.E_x_DEPT_ID